# Initialize XLabs in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, xlabs

I have just added a Windows Phone 8.1 project to my Xamarin app project, but now I can't figure out how to initialize XLabs in it, as it can't find `XFormsAppWP`, so I can't follow the guide at [XLabs's website.](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs#initializing-the-services)
I am using XLabs v. 2.0.5783-pre01.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing Xlabs you must install the nuget in each project that you have.
I've tested now with the Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.31 with the XLabs.Forms 2.2.0-pre02 in a WP8.1 project.

In your `App.xaml.cs` place this:

```
var app = new XFormsAppWin();
app.Init(this);
```

Below the line:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

And add this:

```
using XLabs.Forms;
```

Comment: Is the problem with the removal of Android Resources fixed in pre2?

Comment: Not totally sure but you could try it. I tested with the pre2 but you could use the pre1. You must install it in all of your projects.

Comment: When updating I get this error "Could not install package 'XLabs.Core 2.2.0-pre02'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: Remove all Xlabs dependencies. After that install Xlabs 2.2.0 pre02. Don't  try to update the existing.

Comment: I figured out, it came from the Silverlight project. In some how I don't think, they are supporting it anymore.